# How to sort elements within a list of lists without altering the position of the elements in python?

Tags: python

I have the list:

a = [[7, 3, 5], [9, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

expected output:

b = [[7, 5, 3], [9, 3, 0], [3, 2, 1]]

Thank in advance!

Comment: Sorting by its nature alters positions. Do you mean you want `a` to stay the same and compute an independent object for `b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and use `sorted(l, reverse=True)` to sort each sublist in descending order

```
a = [[7, 3, 5], [9, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
b = [sorted(l, reverse=True) for l in a]
```

Comment: If you want `a` to stay the same, this is it. `sorted` and list comprehensions makes new lists without changing the input. All the `x.sort()` answers do the sorting in-place, therefore they change the input lists in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the list and call `sort` on each inner list.

```
a = [[7, 3, 5], [9, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
for x in a:
    x.sort(reverse=True)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: https://replit.com/@Hsmitty/EducatedClientsideBooleanvalue#main.py

```
a = [[7, 3, 5], [9, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
b = []
for x in a:
  x.sort()
  x.reverse()
  b.append(x)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this can help you

```
a = [[7, 3, 5], [9, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
for idx, item in enumerate(a):
    item.sort(reverse=True)
    a[idx] = item

print(a)
```